# Xquery for-if-then-else unexpected output

Tags: xml, xquery

I am trying to return some output and am I'm having some difficulties, it may very well be I don't have the correct understanding of Xquery for-if-then--else statements.

```
for $S in doc("prac5a.xml")/enrolment
return
  <enrolment>{
    for $s in//student, $e in//enrol
    return
      if($s/id = $e/stud) then
        <student>{$s/id, $s/name, $e/crs}</student>
      else <student>{$s/id, $s/name}</student>
  }</enrolment>
```

From this I was expecting an output of something like;

```
<enrolment>
    <student>
        <id>s1</id>
        <name>John</name>
        <crs>c1</crs>
        <crs>c2</crs>
    </student>
    <student>
        <id>s2</id>
        <name>Peter</name>
        <crs>c2</crs>
        <crs>c3</crs>
    </student>
    <student>
        <id>s3</id>
        <name>Rob</name>
    </student>
```

Instead I get this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enrolment>
   <student>
      <id>s1</id>
      <name>John</name>
      <crs>c1</crs>
      <crs>c2</crs>
   </student>
   <student>
      <id>s1</id>
      <name>John</name>
   </student>
   <student>
      <id>s2</id>
      <name>Peter</name>
   </student>
   <student>
      <id>s2</id>
      <name>Peter</name>
      <crs>c2</crs>
      <crs>c3</crs>
   </student>
   <student>
      <id>s3</id>
      <name>Rob</name>
   </student>
   <student>
      <id>s3</id>
      <name>Rob</name>
   </student>
</enrolment>
```

Why is that? or more importantly I suppose how could I get the desired result.

Comment: What's the original data look like?

Comment: Your question lacks both the input and a description of what you actually want to achieve. Please read [ask] and [how to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer a complete solution without the original data, but your iteration problem is caused by your use of the `for ... in` clause in your FLWOR statement. Multiple variable bindings in the `for ... in` clause is shorthand for nested loops, as this example should demonstrate:

```
for $x in (1, 2), $y in (3, 4)
return $x || "-" || $y
```

returns

```
1-3
1-4
2-3
2-4
```

There's also some typos in your code; `for $s in//student, $e in//enrol` isn't valid XQuery (or could be, but would mean every `student` and `enrol` element in `fn:collection()`). Assuming you intended something like `for $st in $s//student, $e in $st//enrol` (and depending on the structure of your input document), the following change could solve your problem:

```
for $st in $s//student
let $e := $st//enrol
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question is both missing example data and a description what you're trying to achieve, this answer includes some guessing.

Your current query performs a cross product on all students and courses, and returns a new element of a student together with the course if he's visiting it – or a new element with only the student. I *think* what you want is a list of students, together with the courses they're enrolled to. Such a query might be:

```
<enrolment>{ (: Wrapper element for all students :)
  let $doc := doc("prac5a.xml")/enrolment (: Access the document, see note below :)
  for $student in $doc//student (: Loop over all students :)
  return <student>{
    $student/id,
    $student/name,
    $doc/enrol[$student/id = stud] (: Find all enrolments of this particular students, implicit loop :)
  }</student>
}</enrolment>
```

I added some comments on the differences (apart from meaningfull variable names: never use single letter variable names, using descriptive ones is free and reduces lots of complexity for larger fragments of code). One thing to note is where you open the document/database: You bind the content of the *wrapper element* (`<enrolment/>`) to `$S`, but then never use it; instead you're accessing starting at the current context. I explicitly loaded and used that document instead.